# TypeError: order must be str, not int

Tags: python, numpy

```
M = Train.shape[1]

Theta = np.zeros((120,M))
for k in range(M):
 temp = np.reshape(np.copy(Train[:,k]),(m,n))
 tempSmall = resize(temp, (10, 12), anti_aliasing=True)
 Theta[:,k] = np.reshape(tempSmall,120,1)
```

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
57     try:
---> 58         return bound(*args, **kwds)
59     except TypeError:

TypeError: order must be str, not int
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

FULL TRACEBACK:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xJTVtDEl_boFGP2l2uv6WK0EeBCM1vfu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example (e.g. what is `Train` ?) and the full traceback?

Comment: You used `reshape` correctly the first time, but not the second.  Reread its docs.  And for your sake and ours show the full traceback!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xJTVtDEl_boFGP2l2uv6WK0EeBCM1vfu/view?usp=sharing
THIS IS THE LINK FOR FULL TRACEBACK

Comment: The traceback points to line 8, the second `reshape` use.  Call it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code is solve by changing the last line of code by this  syntax

Theta[:,[k]] = np.reshape(tempSmall,(120,1))